# how can i solve following issue: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

```
insert into tbl_cart (ssid,  product_id, product_name, product_price, product_image, quantity) 
values (1234, (select product_id, product_name, product_price, product_image    from tbl_product WHERE product_id=1),1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query:

```
select product_id, product_name, product_price, product_image 
from tbl_product 
where product_id=1
```

returns the columns that you want, but for `INSERT ... VALUES` it is syntactically wrong, to use a query that returns more than 1 column.

Use `INSERT ... SELECT`:

```
insert into tbl_cart (ssid, product_id,product_name,product_price,product_image,quantity) 
select 1234, product_id, product_name, product_price, product_image, 1 
from tbl_product 
where product_id=1;
```